# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Alright , After I made a landing page , I got a problem with the jquery ERROR 
which I dont get

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)  http://****/contact.blade.php

this is contact.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>landin page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js') }}"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/class.FormValidation.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/landin_validation.js' ) }}"></script>

            @include('messages.form_val')
            @include('messages.form_handler')

    </head>
    <body>
```

Comment: Its not jQuery error its your PHP error

Comment: Why it says jquery in console ?

Comment: 500 is s internal **Server** error.That's why you should look in the Server logfiles to find out what the error is.

Comment: you think ajax problem ?

Comment: please check your project laravel.log or server log

Comment: i dont get for today or for this situation in logs

Comment: please provide content of  form_val, form_handler page and also the route responsible for any action related to  these pages.